# Does this message mean I installed tensorflow GPU correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I has installed tensorflow CPU via pip without a hitch, but then I thought, why not get the gpu version?. I ran pip uninstall tensorflow, then downloaded CUDA 9.2 and later realized it wasnt finding a file because it had to be CUDA 9.0. So i uninstalled 9.2 and installed 9.0 and I followed the steps on NVIDIA CUDA docs and added CUDAPATH\9.0\bin and CUDAPATH\9.0\libnvvd to PATH environment variables. I copied over cuDNN 7.0 files into CUDA 9.0 (the lib,include, and x64 files) and I ran python in cmd and imported tensorflow as tf with no error, but then I got that message after tf.Session().

```
    2018-08-09 19:49:02.740730: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
        2018-08-09 19:49:03.477475: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties:
        name: GeForce GTX 960M major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0975
        pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
        totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.65GiB
        2018-08-09 19:49:03.486507: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
        2018-08-09 19:52:16.961533: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
        2018-08-09 19:52:16.972650: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0
        2018-08-09 19:52:16.976165: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N
2018-08-09 19:52:16.985841: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1408 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
```

While not an error message, I feel something is not right. I want to use the GPU and not the CPU for tensorflow, it looks kind of like it is checking both for tensorflow CPU and GPU? **How do I make sure everything is set properly and simply use tensorflow GPU? How do I stop getting this error messsage when I run this tf.Session() ?**  Also, thought I might add, tensorflow is installed in anaconda3 file directory of my computer.

**EDIT**: I have been told that the message I am getting is exactly what I should expect after installing tensorflow gpu.  I will leave the question up and change the question statement so other users with similar questions can benefit from the answers.

[image]

Comment: Hi userP520, it's much easier for us to help you if write the error you received into the body of the question (with a strong preference towards using "code markdown" where appropriate) instead of posting a picture

Comment: I don't know what the concern is.  Everything looks normal.  If you create a TF session on your GPU, it should use the GPU.  There are no errors here.

Comment: So there is no sign of improper installation etc? Is there any sanity check to make sure everything is set properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is ok.

GPU version of tensorflow use both CPU and GPU because not all operation in tensorflow can be placed on GPU.

When a local session is created, tensorflow runtime will find and check all available devices, check information is print on screen just like you can see. If you see no errors, it indicates that you installed tensorflow-gpu properly.

If you want to check for more information, run `nvidia-smi` in command line, you can see  tensorflow process, and gpu memory is used up in default.